# Python selenium webscraping returns cant find the element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have the following webpage where I need to login using username and password.

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-marginNormal MuiFormControl-fullWidth"><label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined Mui-required Mui-required" data-shrink="true">Username<span class="MuiFormLabel-asterisk MuiInputLabel-asterisk"> *</span></label><div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl"><fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss298 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline" style="padding-left: 8px;"><legend class="jss299" style="width: 70.25px;"><span>​</span></legend></fieldset><input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="email username" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" required="" type="text" autocapitalize="none" value=""></div></div>"
```

My code is as below

```
uname = driver.find_element_by_class_name('MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-marginNormal MuiFormControl-fullWidth')
```

However, it returns following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-marginNormal MuiFormControl-fullWidth"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.9
```

please can you help me?

Comment: Anyone please let me know

Comment: <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="email username" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" required="" type="text" autocapitalize="none" >

Comment: How to extract elements in above html code..anyone pls help

Comment: Closed got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the desired field you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.MuiInputBase-root.MuiOutlinedInput-root.MuiInputBase-fullWidth.MuiInputBase-formControl input.MuiInputBase-input.MuiOutlinedInput-input[autocomplete='email username']"))).send_keys("bluemountains1979")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl']//input[@class='MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input' and @autocomplete='email username']"))).send_keys("bluemountains1979")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.